# Can you share a figure slider between two subpanels with plotly.express?

Tags: python, plotly, slider

I want to have a figure with two subplots which are both updated using the same x axis slider with plotly.express.

I have successfully done a single subplot with a slider using a command like:

```
import plotly.express as px

px.line(plot_df, x='context', y='probability',animation_frame='trial',animation_group='t', color="t", range_y=[0,1])
```

but I have no idea how to extend it to having two subplots controlled by the same slider or if this is possible at all. I can obviously add another subplot in the same manner but then the frames will not update synchronously. Any suggestions? Thank you.

***EDIT***

Question wasn't very clear so I am providing example data and extra description:

```
# Example Data for plot A
npi = 8
nc = 4
data = np.zeros([npi,nc,t])
for c in range(nc):
    data[:,c,:] = np.tile(np.arange(npi).reshape(npi,1),t) +     np.random.normal(0,2,size=[npi,t])

pols = np.arange(npi)
ts = np.arange(t)
cs = np.arange(nc)

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pols, cs, ts], names=['policy', 'context', 'trial'])
df = pd.Series(index=mi, data=data.flatten())
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'probability'})

# Desired animation for plot A
px.line(df, x='policy', y='probability',animation_frame='trial',animation_group='context', color="context")

# Example Data for plot B
t = 10
nc = 6
tau = 4
data = np.zeros([nc,tau,t])
for ti in range(tau):
    data[:,ti,:] = np.tile(np.arange(nc).reshape(nc,1),t) + np.random.normal(0,2,size=[nc,t])

conts = np.arange(nc)
ts = np.arange(t)
taus = np.arange(tau)

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([conts, taus, ts], names=['context', 'timepoint', 'trial'])
df = pd.Series(index=mi, data=data.flatten())
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'probability'})

# Desired animation for plot B
px.line(df, x='context', y='probability',animation_frame='trial',animation_group='timepoint', color="timepoint")
```

I want a figure where subplot A and B are plotted next to each other and controlled by the same "trial" slider so I can see their evolution side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- taking your generator code.  `fig1` is first figure, `fig2` is second figure
- now create a new figure that integrates all the traces and frames from both figures.  For traces / frames from second figure put them on **x2 / y2** axes
- finally fix up integrated layout

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# integrate the two figures, putting second figure on separate axis
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[t for t in fig1.data] + [t.update(xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2") for t in fig2.data],
    frames=[
        go.Frame(
            name=fr1.name,
            data=[t for t in fr1.data]
            + [t.update(xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2") for t in fr2.data],
        )
        for fr2, fr1 in zip(fig2.frames, fig1.frames)
    ],
    layout=fig1.layout,
)

# now config axes appropriately
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_domain=[0, 0.49],
    xaxis2={"domain": [0.51, 1], "matches": None, "title":{"text":fig2.layout.xaxis.title.text}},
    yaxis2={"matches":"y"},
    showlegend=False,
)
```

[image]

#### generator code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# Example Data for plot A
t = 10
npi = 8
nc = 4
data = np.zeros([npi,nc,t])
for c in range(nc):
    data[:,c,:] = np.tile(np.arange(npi).reshape(npi,1),t) +     np.random.normal(0,2,size=[npi,t])

pols = np.arange(npi)
ts = np.arange(t)
cs = np.arange(nc)

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pols, cs, ts], names=['policy', 'context', 'trial'])
df = pd.Series(index=mi, data=data.flatten())
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'probability'})

# Desired animation for plot A
fig1 = px.line(df, x='policy', y='probability',animation_frame='trial',animation_group='context', color="context")

# Example Data for plot B
t = 10
nc = 6
tau = 4
data = np.zeros([nc,tau,t])
for ti in range(tau):
    data[:,ti,:] = np.tile(np.arange(nc).reshape(nc,1),t) + np.random.normal(0,2,size=[nc,t])

conts = np.arange(nc)
ts = np.arange(t)
taus = np.arange(tau)

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([conts, taus, ts], names=['context', 'timepoint', 'trial'])
df = pd.Series(index=mi, data=data.flatten())
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'probability'})

# Desired animation for plot B
fig2 = px.line(df, x='context', y='probability',animation_frame='trial',animation_group='timepoint', color="timepoint")

fig2
```

Comment: thanks for the response! 

I am not sure if this will work for me though. I have two distriibutions I am tracking in time and am also looking at them in dependence on different parameters (like color=""t" in original post). So I will have two lineplots which share an "y" and exist for value of the slider but differ in the color parameter and x axis value. I will check out how facet works though and try and adapt it.

Comment: consider making your question clearer.  you mention subplots,  your code is using animation and there is no sample data to consider ...  so many things are possible, but important to clearly show and ask what you need to achieve

Comment: good point, I have provided some example data and better description of what I need.

Comment: ok with clear definition and data,  have reworked answer